# How to create gtk+ windows without title bar?

Tags: linux, gtk

How to create gtk+ windows without title bar(header) in linux?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the [gtk_window_set_decorated](http://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/gtk/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-decorated) function.