# How to create gtk+ windows without title bar with resize and move properties working

Tags: c, gtk

How to create gtk+ windows without title bar with resize and move properties working.
I checked `gtk_window_set_decorated` function, but it disable resize and move features of window. I found [this answer already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516092/how-to-create-gtk-windows-without-title-bar/1516104#1516104?newreg=db72f9175f9a4f53bbfbe945803c23cc), but I don't think it has anything to do with it.

I tried to set resizeable true after gtk_window_set_decorated but still not working

Please check code

```
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>
    int main (int argc,
    char *argv[])
    {  
      GtkWidget *window;
      /* Initialize GTK+ and all of its supporting libraries. */
      gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
      /* Create a new window, give it a title and display it to the user. */
      window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
      gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Hello World");
      gtk_window_set_decorated (GTK_WINDOW (window), FALSE);
      gtk_window_set_resizable (GTK_WINDOW (window), TRUE);
      //gtk_window_set_gravity(GTK_WINDOW (window), GDK_GRAVITY_NORTH_EAST);
      //gtk_window_set_deletable (GTK_WINDOW (window), FALSE);
      gtk_widget_show (window);
      /* Hand control over to the main loop. */
      gtk_main ();
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I'd create the window in Glade, and simply write a GTK+-3.0 style program that creates a builder from that file...

Comment: I tried and cant write a border less window. How to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

So what I found to work is to remove the header with `gtk_window_set_decorated` set to FALSE. Then manually change the cursor and call [`gtk_window_begin_resize_drag()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-begin-resize-drag) to begin a resize on mousedown.

How I implemented this was to check if the mouse was near a border on a mousemove callback and if so change the cursor with [`gdk_window_set_cursor()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#gdk-window-set-cursor).

On a mousedown event near a border I call `gtk_window_begin_resize_drag()` with the appropriate border.

Answer (score 0):

you can use GTK_WINDOW_POPUP :

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
    int main (int argc,
    char *argv[])
    {  
      GtkWidget *window;
      /* Initialize GTK+ and all of its supporting libraries. */
      gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
      window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_POPUP);
      gtk_widget_show (window);
      gtk_main ();
      return 0;
    }
```

You should not use GTK_WINDOW_POPUP if you only want window manager decorations turned off
for the window. Instead, use gtk_window_set_decorated (GtkWindow *window, gboolean show)
to turn off window decorations.

like that :

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc,char *argv[])
{
      GtkWidget *window;
      gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
      window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
      gtk_window_set_decorated (GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);
      gtk_widget_show (window);
      gtk_main ();
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mention that user should try using `GTK_WINDOW_POPUP` and provided a code snippet which can be understood as sample, but it doesn't actually demonstrate any use of `GTK_WINDOW_POPUP`

Comment: Sorry
Changes were added